# google oauth2 implementation using Node JS error

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

Anybody can explain me where to put this following code and what its mean.. it showing error in .js file showing that "OBJECT HAS NO METHOD .discover".

```
googleapis
.discover('calendar', 'v3')
.discover('oauth2', 'v2')
.execute(function(err, client){
if(!err)
callback(client);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of the nodejs client are you using? The .discover() method was removed for version 1.0 and replaced with pre-compiling all the libraries.

See https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md for information about migrating your code to 1.0.